# how do I calculate the days from a calculated column and a column in a table in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

In Access i had the query below and it worked perfectly.

[access sql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8ayE.jpg)
[access result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij9et.jpg)

In SQLite i am having difficulty in caculating days. I have tried julianday,substr etc

> SELECT DISTINCT t1.AccNo, t1.InvDate, ifnull((SELECT     MIN(t1min.InvDate) 
>       FROM t1 AS t1min   WHERE t1min.InvDate > t1.InvDate   AND t1.AccNo = t1min.AccNo),
>   Date('%Y(t1.InvDate)','%m(t1min.InvDate)') +'1 month') AS NextDate,
>   date(NextDate - t1.InvDate ) AS days
>   FROM t1 LEFT JOIN customer ON t1.AccNo=customer.AccNo
>   GROUP BY t1.AccNo, t1.InvDate, t1.NextDate
>   LIMIT 17
>   Blockquote

[result of sqlite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfYcb.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite there is not a special `Date` data type.
Dates are stored as strings and the expression:

```
NextDate - t1.InvDate
```

in your case is evaluated to `0` because both operands, I guess, start with the same integer part, like:

```
'2019-02-01' - '2019-01-01'
```

and in this situation SQLite implicitly converts both to the starting integer part: `2019`.
So the result is `0` and `date(0)` returns `null`.
What you can do to get the difference in days of the 2 dates, is use the function [`julianday()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
julianday(NextDate) - julianday(t1.InvDate) AS days
```

Comment: Thanks Forpas. I have tried the above and i get a null. Is it not because NextDate is a calculated date and there is a null in one of the NextDate.

Comment: @shabz sqlite date and time functions return null when given an argument they can't parse. Make sure your date strings are in one of the supported formats: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: @shabz If your dates have the correct format `YYYY-MM-DD` then `julianday(NextDate) - julianday(t1.InvDate)` will return a correct result. Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a7RrJzoAJYm1s4ZTG93Mnr/0